# Load respond of php document into a textfield - jQuery/Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

i do have a litte problem with my actual project.

My .HTML document gives via post some data to a php document wich is only echoing some numbers and letters but no spaces. So now id like to load that respond directly into a textbox, without showing the "ugly" respond php doc or reloading the site.

thanks for help

Comment: Could you provide your code so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this with jquery.

You will need to capture your response and set the textfield `value` attribute.

If you are getting data perhaps you should use GET method instead of post.

```
$.get('your_php_url?some_data=here&some_more_data=here', function(response, status) {
  if (status === 'success') {
    $('#your_textbox').val(response);    
  }

});
```

Or even better encode your data in JSON instead of passing plain text.

`$.getJSON` and set your textbox to the json response

you can use submit to attach a submit handler to your form. Make sure to return false so the form doesn't go to the action page.

Comment: my form header:
`<form action="pass.php" method="post" id="pwform" class="form-horizontal">`

my form submit 
`<div align="center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-warning">Generieren!</button>
        </div>`


and the textfield `<input name="password" type="text">`

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/mydoc.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data: {tb1: "arbitrary"}, // this could be anything
    success: function(data) {
        $("#myTextBox").val(data);
    }});
```

Hope this helps!